# How to make unlimited variables (like Num1, Num2, etc)?

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb 2012 express (for desktop), and I was wonder how I can make unlimited variables.
For example

```
Dim Num1 as integer
Dim Num2 as integer
```

I want the application to go make a new variable with the Num3,4,5,6 etc.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You dont want to use an array?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? May be there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

Consider using and an array or a list:

```
    Dim Num As New List(Of Integer) 'Create a list of integers
    For i = 0 To Integer.MaxValue 'Add to the list as much as it can hold which is 2147483647 items, it is integer's maximum value.
        Num.Add(0)
    Next

    'OR

    Dim NumArray(Integer.MaxValue) As Integer 'Create an array of integers which holds maximum number of items, again 2147483647 items.

    'Youy may access them both via their indexes:
    Console.WriteLine(Num(0))
    Console.WriteLine(Num(1))
    Console.WriteLine(Num(2))
    'or
    Console.WriteLine(NumArray(0))
    Console.WriteLine(NumArray(1))
    Console.WriteLine(NumArray(2))
    'and so on...
```

Btw, `Console.WriteLine()` converts integers to strings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need arrays for (or possibly a collection class, depending on other needs).

Something like:

```
Dim Idx As Integer
Dim Num(10) As Integer

' Now you can use Num(0) thru Num(10) '
For Idx = 0 To 10
    Num(Idx) = 10 - Idx
Next
```